# NodeJS web app access Azure REST API Authentication fails

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a sample NodeJS App where I will be calling Azure Log Analytics REST API and I have App Registration already done but I am not a Node JS developer and unfortunately stuck here, I got some code from some searching around but this doesnt work at all, can someone help me how I can get this to get Authentication token from NodeJs (I just created a sample Express NodeJs app and pasted the below code) but its not working, if someone can help me with fixing the code:

```
var express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');
const APP_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const APP_SECERET = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT ='https://login.microsoftonline.com/MYTENANTID/oauth2/v2.0/token';
const MS_GRAPH_SCOPE = 'Data.Read';
const resource ='GUID FOR LOG ANALYTICS WORKSPACE';
var responseval = "";


const postData = {
  client_id: APP_ID,
  scope: MS_GRAPH_SCOPE,
  client_secret: APP_SECERET,
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  resource: resource
};

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =
  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

let token = '';

axios
  .post(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, qs.stringify(postData))
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    responseval = response.data;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    responseval = error;
  });

var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express ' + responseval });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Following is my WORKING POWERSHELL CODE which I am trying to get working in NODE.Js

```
$tenantId      = "MYTENANT ID"  #Directory ID for THREE PROJECT





$formData = @{

  client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  client_secret = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

  scope = 'Data.Read';

  grant_type = 'client_credentials';

  resource = 'https://api.loganalytics.io'

}


$uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + $tenantId + '/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0'
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $formData -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

$authHeader = @{

'Content-Type'='application/json'

'Authorization'= 'Bearer ' + $response.access_token

}

$request1 = "https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/LOGANALYTICS WORKSPACE ID/query?query=externalapistatus_CL "

$resultz1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request1 `

                  -Headers $authHeader `

                  -Method Get
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are just writing an http console client so you don't need express. Maybe use [this library](https://github.com/compwright/axios-oauth-client).

For the simplest code use a self executing function like this in an index.js file - then just run 'npm start'

```
const axios = require('axios');
const oauth = require('axios-oauth-client');

(async () => {

const getClientCredentials = oauth.client(axios.create(), {
  url: 'https://oauth.com/2.0/token',
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  client_id: 'foo',
  client_secret: 'bar',
  scope: 'baz'
});

const auth = await getClientCredentials(); // => { "access_token": "...", "expires_in": 900, ... }

})();
```

Comment: Thank you @Gary but my goal is to host a website and display contents from Azure log Analytics, hence i used express but unfortunately some syntactical issue or I m not calling the function properly as I dnt know the basics of Nodejs. After I recieve the access token I need to execute another http post to get data as shown in my powershell. Can you help me with basic script as somewhere that calling of function is failing.

Answer (score 0):

After some little basics knowledge gathering Thanks to Node.JsTutorial by Programming with @Mosh (Youtube Node.Js basics tutorial) I was able to get this working. I built a simple console Node.Js app as suggested by @Gary above and following is the code which returns the token now (Next step now will be to put it in function and use it in web-App):-

```
const axios = require('axios');
const oauth = require('axios-oauth-client');
const qs = require('qs');
const APP_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const APP_SECERET = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT ='https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyTenantID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0';
const MS_GRAPH_SCOPE = 'Data.Read';
const resource ='https://api.loganalytics.io';
var responseval = "";

const postData = {
    client_id: APP_ID,
    scope: resource,
    client_secret: APP_SECERET,
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
  };

  axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    axios
    .post(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, qs.stringify(postData))
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (err){
        console.log(err.response);
    });
```